# How can I remove duplicate SERP results for same domain?

Tags: seo, search-results, local-seo, pagination

When I search "example business near zip code" in Google, I get the following separate, distinct results for the domain:

```
www.example.com/ny/new-york/10019
www.example.com/ny/new-york/10019/?start=10&zip=10019
www.example.com/ny/new-york/10019/?start=20&zip=10019
```

Is this a pagination issue? 
Will these be indexed as duplicate content?

Comment: It really depends what is actually on these URLs, a working example would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Since Google is returning these URLs in their search results, it's unlikely that they're considering them to be [duplicate conten](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359?hl=en)t. As indicated [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359?hl=en), if Google finds duplicate content on your site they:  `do a good job of choosing a version of the content to show in [their] search results.`

If you'd like only one of the URL's to be indexed though, as suggested there you can add a  [rel="canonical"](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139394?hl=en) link element to the other pages to indicate which of the URLs you prefer to be indexed.

Alternatively, you could [specify how Google should handle parameters](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1235687?hl=en) (select the "No URLs" option), or use [301 redirect](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en)s to point the other URLs to the main one.

Sometime after re-crawling your site, Google should drop the extra URLs from your index, but it could take weeks. If they're not impacting your SERP or traffic however, you might just leave things as they are.

Comment: Does having the URLs indexed as unique SERP results have any impact on pagerank? I'm wondering if it is essentially splitting my pagerank across all of these pages instead of consolidating it on the main page. Thoughts?

Comment: You might want to open a new question specific to PageRank. In general, PageRank is per page/document, and weighted less as of late. If you're concerned, you can follow the above (i.e., canonicalization, specifying how to handle parameters, or 301 redirects).